# getElementsByClassName get single element

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I need to add an EventListener function on every div with a certain class, I tried this:

```
 var a = document.getElementsByClassName('linkto');

 for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
 a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
 console.log(a);
 }); }
```

But that gives me all the divs. My divs are generated in a foreach loop:

```
 @foreach($faqs['My_Stay'] as $faqheading)
      <div class="row  lowboarder linkcolor-darkblue linkto">
          {{ link_to('#div'.$faqheading->id,$faqheading->heading) }}
      </div>
 @endforeach
```

Is there a good way to determine which div was clicked on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like below, "this" inside your click function refer to the clicked div

```
for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
 a[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
 console.log(this.innerText);
 }); }
```